# Attach "class" to Array prototype

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this "class":

```
function FindArrayObject(arr, property, value) {

    var $this = this;
    [ some code here ]
    return $this;

}

FindArrayObject.prototype.index = function() {
    return this.result;
};
FindArrayObject.prototype.element = function() {
    return ( this.result === -1 ? false : 'Something else' );
};
```

But I want to attach it to Array prototype, so I don't need to init it with `new FindArrayObject` and passing the array.

One big problem is that `this` will reference array and not the class, so I don't know if we can, also 'cause the "sub" functions without `this` can't retrieve the values, but I try to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary to return `$this`? Also i don't think that can be done. Yes you might like to use `call(), bind(), apply()` methods.

Comment: $this is a "deepcopy" of this because "this" will be overwritten by "array.some". In $this I set the result variable fetched by index and element

Comment: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch6.html#don-t-construct-by-returning-objects-use-prototype-and-new

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.FindArrayObject = [function body]`. This will make the function available to all arrays you initialize in the scope of your script.

Comment: Sure, but I need the other two functions (index and element) that fetch a value set by FindArrayObject ( this.result )

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.FindArrayObject = function (arr,property, value) {

    var $this = this;
    [ some code here ]

}
```

You can use it like this

```
var a = new Array.prototype.FindArrayObject([],'','')
```